# Fast matrix operation library for Android App

Tags: android, java, matrix

I am working on an android app which needs to do some quick matrix operations (inverse transpose matrix multiplications etc) As I understand there are already many fast libraries for doing such operations on matrices in Java. Jblas is one of them I know.

The number of times the operations are needed is less i.e. I do not need to do hundreds of operations very fast, every second. but I do need that the few times those operations are required, it should not take too long. The matrices can be or various sizes - 5x5, 10x10.. up to 50x50 in some cases.

I would like to know which option would be best to use in and android app and how to actually use it in my application? Do I just import the JAR and use it like I would on any normal Java application?
I was thinking that including the JAR would increase the size of my App, so is that really a good idea?

I am relatively new to Android development but I have been working on Java for quite a few years now. So, any help from the android experts would be much appreciated.